# Como eu faço para colocar o checkbox do lado da label?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sneake</title>

    <style>
      
      body{
          font-family: Gilroy,sans-serif;
          font-weight: 700;
          font-size: 32px;
          line-height: 32px;
      }

      .formulario{
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 550px;
        background: #F3F3F3;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 30px;
      }

      .formulario input{
          color: gray;
          width: 300px;
          height: 30px;
          border-radius: 10px;
          margin: 8px;
      }

      textarea{
          width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
          margin: 8px;
          border-radius: 10px;
      }
      .caixa-selecao{
          font-size: 12px;
          border: 1px solid red;

      }

     .botao{
         border: 1px solid black;
         padding: 15px 120px;
         border-radius: 10px;
         line-height: 20px;
         font-weight: bold;   
         cursor: pointer;
     }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <h1>Corra</h1> 
        <h1>como se o mundo</h1> 
        <h1>dependesse de você</h1>
        <img>
    </div>


        <form class="formulario">
            <h2>Contacte-nos</h2>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nome"><br>
            <input type="email" placeholder="email"><br>
            
            <textarea placeholder="comentários"></textarea>

            <div class="caixa-selecao">
                <label>Concordo com a política de privacidade</label>
                <input type="checkbox">
            </div>
           
            <button class="botao">Enviar dados</button>
            
        </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

insira o código aqui

Comment: Cara mas o seu input tem 300px da largura.... e o seu formulário 400px, como vc quer que caiba o texto

Comment: @hugocsl uma boa solução para o caso dele seria colocar um `.formulario input[type="checkbox"]` e definir um `width: auto;`? Foi a primeira coisa que pensei :)

Answer (score 0):

Por causa do seu `.formulario input` onde você definiu `width: 300px;`, **isto também está fazendo o seu `<input type="checkbox" />` ter `width` de `300px`**, e pelo fato de seu formulário ter limite de `400px;`, isso faz com que seu texto e o input sejam exibidos em linhas diferentes e não lado a lado.

Para resolver isso, e tentando manter seu código do jeito que está, bastaria você simplismente adicionar uma propriedade no CSS para sobreescrever o `width` do checkbox. Basta adicionar, logo após `.formulario input{...}`, a seguinte propriedade:

```css
.formulario input[type='checkbox'] {
   width: auto;
 }
```

Isso vai fazer o checkbox ter a uma largura definida automáticamente e fará com que o texto seja exibido ao lado do input.

Veja como fica:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sneake</title>

    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Gilroy, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 32px;
        line-height: 32px;
      }

      .formulario {
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 550px;
        background: #f3f3f3;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 30px;
      }

      .formulario input {
        color: gray;
        width: 300px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin: 8px;
      }

      .formulario input[type='checkbox'] {
        width: auto;
      }

      textarea {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 8px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      .caixa-selecao {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid red;
      }

      .botao {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 15px 120px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        line-height: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Corra</h1>
      <h1>como se o mundo</h1>
      <h1>dependesse de você</h1>
      <img />
    </div>

    <form class="formulario">
      <h2>Contacte-nos</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" /><br />
      <input type="email" placeholder="email" /><br />

      <textarea placeholder="comentários"></textarea>

      <div class="caixa-selecao">
        <label>Concordo com a política de privacidade</label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </div>

      <button class="botao">Enviar dados</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### Pra ficar bonito...

Não ficou com um alinhamento legal, não é? Posso sugerir que você faça um alinhamento do label com o input pra ficar mais bonito. Para isso, na sua propriedade `.caixa-selecao`, você pode adicionar um `display: flex;` e fazer o alinhamento vertical e horizontal centralizado, usando  `align-items: center;` e `justify-content: center;`.

Sua `.caixa-selecao` ficaria assim:

```css
 .caixa-selecao {
   font-size: 12px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
 }
```

Veja o resultado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Sneake</title>

    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Gilroy, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 32px;
        line-height: 32px;
      }

      .formulario {
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 400px;
        height: 550px;
        background: #f3f3f3;
        float: right;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 30px;
      }

      .formulario input {
        color: gray;
        width: 300px;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin: 8px;
      }

      .formulario input[type='checkbox'] {
        width: auto;
      }

      textarea {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 8px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      .caixa-selecao {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .botao {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 15px 120px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        line-height: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>Corra</h1>
      <h1>como se o mundo</h1>
      <h1>dependesse de você</h1>
      <img />
    </div>

    <form class="formulario">
      <h2>Contacte-nos</h2>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" /><br />
      <input type="email" placeholder="email" /><br />

      <textarea placeholder="comentários"></textarea>

      <div class="caixa-selecao">
        <label>Concordo com a política de privacidade</label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </div>

      <button class="botao">Enviar dados</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```